# Oracle Error: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29259: end-of-input reached

Tags: web, service, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to call [Eloqua API](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCBB/) using [apex_web_service.make_rest_request()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI537) from PL/SQL (using SQL Developer)

```
 v_clob_body := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
    p_url              => 'https://secure.p02.eloqua.com/API/Bulk/2.0/contacts/exports/1/data?offset=0',
    p_http_method      => 'GET',
    p_username         => null,
    p_password         => null,
    p_proxy_override   => '<proxy>',
    p_transfer_timeout => 6000,
    p_body             => null,
    p_body_blob        => empty_blob(),
    p_wallet_path      => '<wallet_path>',
    p_wallet_pwd       => '<wallet_pwd>');
```

When trying to execute the GET call, it's throwing the following exception:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1258
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 615
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 657
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 202
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

I also do a POST call, before the GET, and it is working perfectly:

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json; charset utf-8';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Authorization';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'Basic <encoded_user_and_pass>';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).name := 'Accept';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).value := 'application/json; charset utf-8';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(4).name := 'Content-Length';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(4).value := LENGTH(<length>);
    
v_clob_body := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
    p_url              => 'https://secure.p02.eloqua.com/API/Bulk/2.0/customObjects/1/exports',
    p_http_method      => 'POST',
    p_username         => null,
    p_password         => null,
    p_proxy_override   => '<proxy>',
    p_transfer_timeout => 900,
    p_body             => <body>,
    p_body_blob        => empty_blob(), 
    p_wallet_path      => '<wallet_path>',
    p_wallet_pwd       => '<wallet_pwd>');
```

With Fiddler it works perfectly, for both calls.
I tried to increase the `p_transfer_timeout` parameter, but it still doesn't work.
Has anybody had the same issue when using `apex_web_service.make_rest_request()`?

Thank you,
Iulia